# Use Jmeter function value as variable in request

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to wrap my head around Jmeter functions and how to actually use them in an HTTP JSON request. All examples I've found on function use them as titles in HTTP requests, which is not helpful.

All I want to do is this, and then use that variable in my POST request. But that doesn't work and I have no clue why not.

[image]

```
...
"dates": {
"invoiceDate": ${testdate},
...
```

In all examples I've seen, the function is set as the HTTP sampler name, like so:[image]

This is not helpful at all since I can't use that as a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't think `20211` is the valid year, do you mean `2021`?
2. If you put the function inside [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) - it will be evaluated only once and won't be random, you should rather inline it into the request body as User Defined Variables are evaluated **only once**, when the test starts

   [image]
3. If you're trying to post [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) - I think you should surround the function with quotation marks, otherwise the JSON will be invalid. Suggested change:

   ```
   {
       "dates" : {
           "invoiceDate": "${__RandomDate(,,2021-06-20,,)}"
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Putting the function within quotation marks was the key thing here. It's surprising since you don't need to do that for variables. ${someDate} works just fine in JSON so I figured it was the same with functions. Oh well, thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, the key was my stupidity. I didn't realize the date came out as non-string. So it worked all along, I was wrong on my output format expectations

Comment: EDIT: ${someDate} doesn't work without quotation marks of course... since JSON demands strings.